# Typescript error and Declaration or statement expected

Tags: typescript

I am getting the error in this file, but I don't see anything wrong, do you?
I remove each statement one by one, and the error doesn't go away until the file is empty.

Of cours, I'd expect an errant or problem "}" etc.. but I don't see anything.
[image]

**global.d.ts**

```
declare module '*.scss' {
  const content: {[className: string]: string};
  export = content;
}

declare global {
  type Dictionary<T> = {[key: string]: T};
}

type GenericFunction = (...any: any[]) => any;
type GenericObject = {
  [key: string]: string
}

declare global {
  interface Window {
    addEventListener:any;
    adEventListener:any
  }
}
```

Have a secondary question. Should you nest the declare global items under one 'global'? (( btw, I did nest and that didn't fix the issue )).

Comment: Use `,` instead of `;` inside the `interface` declaration.

Comment: `declare global` is for use in modules.